# POSTGRES - COPY from file with seting one value which is not in FILE

Tags: postgresql, csv

I COPY data from my .csv to my postgres table. My command looks like:

```
 COPY w_spare_part_cze (country, manufacturer, model, submodel, guid, model_options, oen, price, description) FROM '/tmp/SpareParts.csv' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',' QUOTE '"';
```

This looks cool, however in my database I have column `country` but in my `.csv` I dont have this column at all ( just have manufacturer, model, submodel, guid, model_options,etc...)

As soon as all the values from this IMPORT is going to have same value for country. Is there a way how to SET IT without locally upload it to another table, add new column with default value, dump and upload again to real table.

Thanks for any advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `country` from field list in `copy` :

```
COPY w_spare_part_cze (manufacturer, model, submodel, guid, model_options, oen, price, description) 
FROM '/tmp/SpareParts.csv' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',' QUOTE '"';
```

and fill the column with desired value:

```
UPDATE w_spare_part_cze 
SET country = 'Japan';
```

---

If the file contains `null` as `country`, temporarily drop not null constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE w_spare_part_cze ALTER country DROP NOT NULL;

COPY w_spare_part_cze (country, manufacturer, model, submodel, guid, model_options, oen, price, description) 
FROM '/tmp/SpareParts.csv' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',' QUOTE '"';

UPDATE w_spare_part_cze 
SET country = 'Japan';

ALTER TABLE w_spare_part_cze ALTER country SET NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Hi @klin, yea this is nice way how to do it, however it don't even want me to import this CSV because it will create rows with country = NULL which is not acceptable by tables rules

Comment: Or add a `DEFAULT` expression for the duration of the import.